# How to get data of specific file ID in Google REST query?

Tags: rest, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, oauth2-playground

I was experimenting the GoogleDrive-v3 REST apis in OAuth2 playground. In that I was trying to filter the field for the specific file info from the response with the file ID/filename.

```
{
    "mimeType": "image/png", 
    "kind": "drive#file", 
    "id": "PuwuUXGsjLaf6gxyrye_g7OmMw", 
    "name": "google.png"
}
```

Here, I pasted my REST query to filter the file info with the file ID "PuwuUXGsjLaf6gxyrye_g7OmMw".
But, it doesn't filter the response for the specified file ID. Instead it print complete response of the REST query.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files&id=PuwuUXGsjLaf6gxyrye_g7OmMw
```

Correct me what I am missing here.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could understand about what you want, if you want to retrieve the file information with the file ID, how about this endpoint? ``GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### fileId ###?fields=*`` or ``GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/### fileId ###``. The official document is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get). If this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the result you want to retrieve?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
Actually, I want to know how to implement the relational operation in google drive rest query from OAuth2 playground.
And I want to retrieve the file info with the file ID or with the file name by comparing the filename as shown below instead of using the above query you suggested.

Example: 
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files where filename = "filename.txt"

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to search a file using the filename. If my understanding is correct, how about using ``q`` of the list method of Drive API? When you want to search ``filename.txt``, the endpoint is ``GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name='filename.txt'``. ``name='filename.txt'`` might need to URL encode. The official documents are [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters).

Comment: Thanks, Tanaike. It is worked !.
It helped me to proceed to further experiment in OAuth2 playground :)

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved. Can you post an answer and accept it? By this, other users can see your question as the resolved question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query parameter "q" can be used to retrieve the file info with the file ID or with the filename.

Here, I retrieved the file *"ubuntu_logo.png"* with the filename from my google drive.

**For Example:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=name='ubuntu_logo.png'
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "incompleteSearch": false, 
  "files": [
    {
      "mimeType": "image/png", 
      "kind": "drive#file", 
      "id": "11n2avML9mfI3IzS57qxV7aT1_uLxM8Wv", 
      "name": "ubuntu_logo.png"
    }
  ], 
  "kind": "drive#fileList"
}
```